# "Cannot find matching stream" error while using FFMPEG filter_complex to mute selected audio channel

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, video, wav

```
ffmpeg  -i stereoaudio.wav -filter_complex "[0:a]atrim=start=0:duration=5[a1];[0:a]atrim=start=5:duration=17,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b2];[b2]pan=stereo|c1=c1[c3];[a1][c3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[d4];[0:a]atrim=start=22:duration=0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[e5];[d4][e5]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out1]" -map [out1] muteLeftfor17seconds.wav


ffmpeg  -i stereoaudio.wav -filter_complex 
"[0:a]atrim=start=0:duration=5[a1];
[0:a]atrim=start=5:duration=17,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b2]; 
[b2]pan=stereo|c1=c1[c3];
[a1][c3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[d4];
[0:a]atrim=start=22:duration=0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[e5];
[d4][e5]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out1]" -map [out1] muteLeftfor17seconds.wav
```

I have written the above ffmpeg command to hopefully take in a stereo wav file, mute a selected channel for a selected amount of time.

**Whenever I run the above command I receive an error that says "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 2 on filter Parsed_concat_4"**

I've done some research on this and it seeems "cannot find matching stream" usually occurs when the stream labels are not aligned correctly, this could be the case however I've been looking at my command for so long that everything is starting to run together lol. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `[a1][c3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[d4]` and `[d4][e5]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out1]`, the `n` value has to match the number of inputs, actually 2 as shown.

In any case, for the given use case, you can just use the aeval filter.

```
ffmpeg  -i in.wav -af "aeval=0|val(1):c=same:enable='between(t\,5\,22)'" out.wav
```

Comment: thank you! this is very helpful. If you dont mind me asking- If wanted to switch to the right channel how would I do that? I tried changing "aeval=0|val(1)" to "aeval=0|val(0)" and this worked, but only for part of the duration I had set

Comment: What do you mean by switching to the right channel?